# How to change the name of specific files in various folders

Tags: bash

I have 1000 files .txt and each file is stored in a folder. I want to add a number to each file.

Let me explain in more details but simpler.

Lets assume I have 10 folders their names are *0, 1, 2, 3, .... 10*
Then I have a file names , dump.trg in each of the folder. 
I want to add a number to each dump.trg so I will have dump0.trg in the folder 0, I will have dump1.trg in the folder 1 etc etc.

I tried to do it with the following but I could not

```
a=0
for i in *dump.trg; do
  new=$(printf "$*.trg" "$a") 
  mv -i -- "$i" "$new"
  let a=a+1
done
```

Can you please tell me how would you do this ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your description I would simply do

```
for i in *; do
    mv -i -- "$i/dump.trg" "$i/dump${i}.trg"
done
```

Alternatively, if you have other files in the current directory (or other subdirectories without a `dump.trg`):

```
for i in */dump.trg; do
    mv -i -- "$i" "${i%.trg}${i%/*}.trg"
done
```

`${i%.trg}` is the filename without its `.trg` suffix (`foo/dump.trg` -> `foo/dump`).

`${i%/*}` is the filename without its `/...` suffix (`foo/dump.trg` -> `foo`). Effectively it gets the directory name from `$i`.

Comment: I'd guard with `[[ -f "$i/dump.trg" ]] && mv ...`

Comment: Also, `for i in */` to restrict the loop to subdirectories only.

Comment: it's OK to have multiple slashes: `ls -l ~///.bash*`, just unsightly. Anyway, better than getting errors due to treating a non-directory file like it's a directory.

Answer (score 1):

Using the [perl-flavoured `rename`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/file-rename.1p.html)

```
mkdir {0..12}
touch {0..12}/dump.trg
rename -n 's{ ([^/]+) (/dump) (\.trg) }{$1$2$1$3}x' */dump.trg
```

```
rename(0/dump.trg, 0/dump0.trg)
rename(1/dump.trg, 1/dump1.trg)
rename(10/dump.trg, 10/dump10.trg)
rename(11/dump.trg, 11/dump11.trg)
rename(12/dump.trg, 12/dump12.trg)
rename(2/dump.trg, 2/dump2.trg)
rename(3/dump.trg, 3/dump3.trg)
rename(4/dump.trg, 4/dump4.trg)
rename(5/dump.trg, 5/dump5.trg)
rename(6/dump.trg, 6/dump6.trg)
rename(7/dump.trg, 7/dump7.trg)
rename(8/dump.trg, 8/dump8.trg)
rename(9/dump.trg, 9/dump9.trg)
```

Remove the `-n` option to actually rename the files.